# CGImageRef to char* array

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa, cgimage

I need to get a raw BRGA data from a window. From what I've seen the common whay to do so is:

```
    int bgraDataLen = 0;
    CGImageRef windowImage = CGWindowListCreateImage(CGRectNull, kCGWindowListOptionIncludingWindow, windowId, kCGWindowImageBoundsIgnoreFraming);

    CFDataRef bgraDataRef = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(windowImage));
    bgraDataLen = CFDataGetLength(bgraDataRef);
    *bgraData = new unsigned char[bgraDataLen]; //This is what I need
    CFDataGetBytes(bgraDataRef, CFRangeMake(0, bgraDataLen), *bgraData);
    CGImageRelease(windowImage);
    CFRelease(bgraDataRef);
```

My problem with this solution is that CGDataProviderCopyData makes a copy of the whole buffer. I want to avoid it and need only a pointer to the raw data. And I don't mind it to be read-only. Is there a better way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Knee-jerk: no, there isn't. An image ref isn't guaranteed to have image data the CPU can access at all, or data in any particular format. The data being held may also mutate. So the copy semantics provide a well signposted way to say "give me the data and let me look after it".

Examples:

- you're snapshotting something on the GPU, so that may not be in the CPU's address space and may well be in a GPU-specific format (they don't tend to be laid out linearly because that's cache inefficient for quite a few common GPU use cases). If you only ever draw to another GPU buffer then the data may never make it to the CPU.
- you've used `CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider`, in which case the API reserves the right not to decode that PNG until it is actually used, then to decode it to any format it thinks is appropriate. So the image silently mutates.